# How to integrate OpenNI, NITE libraries in CodeBlocks or Geany

Tags: kinect, codeblocks, openni, geany

I installed the OpenNI+NITE+kinect on ubuntu 12.10 today and the samples are working fine.  (Ran NITE samples and they work like charm)

I want to start developing in Linux and I like to work with IDE. For ubuntu I have always used Geany or Codeblocks and i was wondering if there was a way to integrate OpenNI,NITE libraries to the IDE's so that I can write, execute, debug the code easily from the IDE itself.

I tried to add the libraries myself in geany but all my attempts failed. :/

Also, when I do `make` for Sample examples in OpenNI, I get *.d and *.o files but I dont seem to get the executable *.out . So i am not sure how to run the programs.

I am a novice programmer, just starting to learn, So please excuse the noobness in 
questions.

Appreciate the Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you're doing something non-trivial with Geany you will need to provide your own build system (even simple GNU Make files will do). Geany is intentionally build system agnostic and allows you to run arbitrary build commands which are described [in the manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#global-tags) as well as in a helpful article [on the wiki](https://wiki.geany.org/howtos/configurebuildmenu).

If you describe in more detail the errors/problems you referred to as "attempts failed" it will likely be possible to provide more concrete solutions.